# Trouble with a vtable -- is it me, or the library?

Tags: com, dll, vtable

I'm trying to use a COM library that makes use of a vtable. However, something funky is going on with the stack after I call the functions, which tells me I'm doing something wrong.

The header file with the vtable definition is pasted here: [pastebin.com/m2d66c18c](http://pastebin.com/m2d66c18c) (see in particular the code starting at line 810). An example is pasted here: [pastebin.com/m1b46e662](http://pastebin.com/m1b46e662).

The table is being filled with the correct locations for the functions, but when I call the function(s), they appear to be looking in the wrong locations for the arguments on the stack. Also, after calling the functions in the table, the stack is messed up and my program crashes. I've tried changing the function type to both `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` but this does nothing.

It's either my code or the library, and the company that wrote the library hasn't gotten back to me -- because it's the weekend, I'm assuming. Also, there is a demo application that utilizes the library, and it works -- so I think it's my code/compiler (gcc)/something else, not the library.

Could it be that there something in particular that you need to do in order to use a COM library?

Comment: Your looks allright. Think of it this way: how is your code different from the demo project? I suppose the solution is in that difference.

Comment: Btw, what if you instead use the symbol ITextGRABSDK_CaptureFromHWND defined in the header?

Comment: It looks exactly the same to me. Only thing that I'm not doing in the example is a call to CoInitialize()... I tried that, still get the problem.

As far as the ITextGRABSDK_CaptureFromHWND macro, that just expands to exactly what I'm doing in the code.

Comment: Will you please pastebin or provide the link to the source of the sample?

Comment: There are a few files involved, so I think the easiest way would be for you to download the installer, which installs the source code examples: renovation-software.com.

It's the first entry on the front page. The example I used is under Program Files\TextGRAB SDK\src\demo. Their example is in C++, but I converted it to C using the header file they provided as a reference.

They got back to me and said it looks like an issue with GCC/reverse stack-order arguments; however, I tried the example in VC++ and it still gave me problems. Also, cdecl and stdcall push args in reverse order.

Thanks.

Comment: You only need CoInitialize() for marshalling and CoCreateInstance() to work, otherwise you'll perfectly do without it. Which one did you try with VC++ - the original or the C variant?

Comment: I tried the example I linked to in my original post with VC++... the original example wouldn't compile for me with VC++ (missing requirements, or something like that). I tried compiling it both as a C and as a C++ file in VC++. For the C++ version, I changed "(textCapLib.sdk)->lpVtbl->CaptureFromHWND()" to "(textCapLib.sdk)->CaptureFromHWND()".

Regardless, I need to get this working with GCC anyway, since that's what my entire program is compiled with. If the vtable is being filled with the correct function addresses, I'm thinking it's gotta be a calling convention/other stack issue?

Comment: Well, looks like that. You should carefully examine the manuals of VC++ and gcc for descriptions of calling conventions.

Comment: You should also check what exactly are the calling convention defines expanded into. We have our own COM components and I just tried using it the same way you do - compiled a sample in VC++7 in "C source" mode. A method with two arguments is called okay.

Comment: The library developer got back to me. Apparently it was a compatibility problem with their library and the MinGW/GCC compiler. They provided an updated version, and now it works.

Thanks a lot for working on this with me. If I could give you points I would.

Comment: What exactly was the incompatibility?